# Returning Rows from Search in Excel

Tags: excel, search, excel-2007, rows

I have a really hard time explaining things so I apologize in advance if some things, or everything, doesn't make sense. Okay, so here's my dilemma. I have a spreadsheet with a couple columns (shown here separated by "|"):

Time | User | Bytes Sent | Server ID

The data in the sheet is collected at irregular intervals. The script that gets the data samples the cumulative amount of bytes sent by "User" to "Server ID" and puts in the time it was sampled, then goes to the next row.

The values are sorted according to time. What I need to do is calculate the average bitrate based on the time the sample was received and the number of bytes sent. The difficult part is that this calculation should only be done on rows that match the "ID" and "Server" that the user searches for. On top of that, this all has to be automated because I'm making it for some tech support people who, like me, have very limited knowledge in Excel.

What I was thinking about doing was searching through the sheet and putting the rows that have the matches into a different sheet, then do a simple calculation on that sheet to get the average bitrate. My question is, how would I extract those rows?

Comment: Yes, the row has to have ID and Server that match search terms given in a different sheet. I'm trying to find average bitrate, so I'll calculate the difference of bytes sent in 2 rows and divide that by the difference of time in those two rows.

Comment: It's a cumulative amount of bytes sent. Basically every user is always sending data. When the script gets a sample, it gets how many bytes were sent to a certain server since a preset time.

Comment: No, you were right. It is the time of day. Perhaps I misunderstood your first question..

Comment: The counter resets when it reaches a preset value. I think I'll just tell my boss that it isn't worth putting this functionality in or let the tech support guys figure it out. It really isn't difficult to do it by hand. Automating it is a whole different animal.

Comment: Could you maybe provide some sample values from the spreadsheet and the desired results?

Answer (score 1):

Ok here is how you do it in Excel 2007/2010.

I did it in a table so to do it this way (you can change the table references to cells and do it that way) you need to convert that data to a table and I named my table "data".

[image]

The cell with the '4' in it is named "server_cell" and the cell with the 'd' in it is named "user_cell"

I entered this formula in the cell where you see a '10':

`=SUMPRODUCT((--data[server]=server_cell)*(data[user]=user_cell)*(data[@bytes]/data[time]))`

Now when if I change the '4' to a '1' and the 'd' to 'p' that 10 changes to 0 because it wasn't found.

[image]

Comment: Based on your input (server 4 and user x), the search shouldn't return anything. The idea is that if I search server 19 and user q, it will return that row and any other rows that contain server 19 and user q. If I search server 19 and user m, it will return nothing in the case of this data.

Comment: If you enter a combination not in that table it returns 0.  Otherwise it returns the bytes/time.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. But now the issue is that the bytes/time isn't giving the current bitrate. It has to be the (difference of two bitrates)/(the difference of two times).

Comment: So what would an example situation be using the above data? Nm I gotcha.  If you gave it '4' and 'd' it would need to average with the '1' and 'x' row values.  That is actually pretty easy to fix.  All you would do is add a column with running time sums and running byte sums.

Comment: Let's change the data of time = 1 to : user = x, bytes = 40, and server = 1. It's also worth mentioning that data is cumulative. So, user x sends 20 bytes between time = 1 to time = 2. This means that total bytes sent is 40 at time = 2. Also, time is time of day. So, we search for user x, server 1. This finds two results. Now, it subtracts 40 bytes from 20, and subtracts time = 2 from 1, which leads to 20 bytes per unit of time.

Comment: I might just forego this functionality. The tech support guys should be able to figure something out by themselves. Thank you very much for your help. I admit the way the data is logged is very strange and difficult to deal with.